# How to transform a wigner function to represent loss of mode information (coarse graining)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, wigner-transform

I have a highly multi-mode gaussian wigner function representing an optical field:

$$W\left(\{p\},\{q\}\right)=\mathrm{Exp}\left(-\sum_{j=0}^{f}(b_{j}q^{2}_{j}+a_{j}p^{2}_{j})\right).$$

However the detector I am modeling can only distinguish "groupings" of the modes labelled by by $j$ (i.e. there are only a few distinguishable modes but thousands of physical modes). In a sense many physical modes are "coarse grained" into a detection mode.

Normally I would just use a POVM for the detection function containing a sum of all the modes in question, but for somewhat complicated reasons (that are not relevant to the question) I can not do this. Instead I'm trying to figure out how to perform such a (non-unitary) transformation to the mode variables themselves.

Does anyone know how to apply such a transformation to the wigner function?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question might be too broad... Unlike density matrices which are positive semidefinite operators, the Wigner function in phase space is not. (Conversely, a classical positive definite phase space Liouville density Wigner transforms to a *non*-positive definite "Groenewold operator", [Bracken and Wood](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407052).)

You might consider, if you already haven't, the [Husimi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husimi_Q_representation), which, being a [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform#Low-pass_filter) of the Wigner function, corresponds to *low-pass filtering* thereof,
and is, in fact, positive semidefinite---the price paid for [loss of information](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf), aggressively non-unitary to be sure, due to this Gaussian blurring. (There are further well-known deficiencies of the Husimi distribution, such as the *substantial   deformation* of the square of the angular momentum, in some contrast to the plain Wigner map, which simply shifts that from its classical value by a mere constant.)

Or a discrete analog thereof.

But it might help if your question were narrower and more specific.